# Javascript json data gets trimmed on append inside each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The json data gets trimmed passing to the element of the input I want to be able to pass the data as an input and be able to edit it, but the data getting  trimmed.

```
Example:        
Expected in input: John Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj) 
Output: John 


$.each(jsonData, (index, value) => {
            tbrow = $("<tr class='some-click'></tr>");
            tbrow.append("<td><input class='some-control'type='text' value="+value.Description+"></td>");
            $("#edit-person").append(tbrow);        
});

Sample JSON Data

"Class": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Description": "John Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj)",
      "Class": "0",
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Description": "Jane Hathaway - Class 2017 (with 11 of 11 subj)",
      "Class": "0",
    }
  ]
```

How can I pass the json data in the value attribute without being trimmed? When I console the data its gets the data but when passed to the attribute it gets trimmed, is it because of the white spaces?

Comment: Please provide an example of the JSON that's actually formatted as JSON, so we can see what's going on. And what do you mean with 'gets trimmed' ? Is there whitespace in front and behind the name that is significant? Or do you mean that the last name and class part is not included in the name field inside the JSON text? I have a hunch that your JSON text, when parsed, will have a name, a surname and class property and such, so you would need something like: `value.Name + ' - ' + value.Surname + ' - ' + value.Class`

Comment: Your provided JSON example will not produce the output `john` in your own code, since there's no name property inside the classes. If this JSON is correct, you want `value.Description` instead of `value.Name`, since the only properties available on objects inside the shown Class array are `ID`, `Description` and `Class`.

Comment: @Shilly I added a json data. I want to get the whole data inside the attribute input and be able to edit the whole 'John Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj)' but the html display like this value="John" Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj)

Comment: @Shilly Sorry copied the wrong code supposed to be 'value.Description' changed it

Comment: If that is the output, your quotes are wrong.

Comment: @Shilly this quotes = "tbrow.append("<td><input class='some-control'type='text' value="+value.Description+"></td>");" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are not correct when constructing the HTML string.

Try:

```
'<td><input class="some-control" type="text" value="' + value.Description + '"></td>'
```

You can see that in your original code you had this: `value="+value.Description+"`, but you also used `"` to start the HTML string, so the value tag became `value=John Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj)` instead of `value="John Lemon - Class 2018 (with 12 of 12 subj)"`, so the HTML engine tried inserting quotes itself, resulting in the mangled HTML you had.